# Ubuntu 16.04 wired connection not being detected

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I'm not able to connect to the internet from the past 2 days, I looked at many similar posts but none of them works for me. I am very new to ubuntu and this is very annoying please help

Things I have tried:
Tried to restart my network manager which failed

```
sudo restart network-manager

restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

then I looked at `ifconfig -a` eth0 is not being recognized at all, the output is

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:147010 (147.0 KB)  TX bytes:147010 (147.0 KB)

wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:bb:58:2b:14:35  
          inet addr:192.168.43.254  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4838:90b3:dca2:86ce/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2405:204:531e:115a:7e2e:5204:7145:83ae/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6611860 (6.6 MB)  TX bytes:1935577 (1.9 MB)
```

I also tried to change the `/etc/network/interfaces` file
from this :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

to this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

nothing seems to work.
please help..

Output from `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

Comment: I suggest you reinstall: sudo apt-get install network-manager

Comment: @saviour123 nope, it did not work either, im getting the same error message..

Comment: The last line of `ifconfig -a` shows an Ethernet controller. So there is hardware present. Did you accidentally disable Networking? Click on the double arrow/wifi icon to check a tick next to Networking.

Comment: @WillemK no, networking is enabled.. :(

Comment: Do you see any leds at the connector?  If you boot Live USB does it work then?

Comment: I dont have any leds attached, the internet wire is directly connected to the laptop.. @WillemK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw this post and downloaded the drivers.. and i did these steps and got my connection back.. still have no idea what went wrong..

First downloaded these files:

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.040.00-1_all.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu6_all.deb

```
sudo dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.040.00-1_all.deb dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu6_all.deb

sudo modprobe -r r8169

sudo modprobe r8169
```

and voila i got my connection back..
Thanks for all the help...

Comment: I'm interested... does the interface still show as `eth0`?

Comment: no.. it has a different name.. wpl6s0, and another problem which i am facing now is that every time i switch on my laptop i have to run that last command in order to start my wired connection, else my laptop won't recognise that there is an Ethernet port connected.. @WillemK

Comment: I cannot find the post, but I vaguely remember a case where the network card also wasn't recognized at startup and if I remember correctly it had to do with powersave. Sorry I cannot be more specific. But if you only have to enter that last command, you can put it in your login profile.

Comment: Im very new to ubuntu, i just hope this does not cause any further problems to me, i will add that command in the startup... @WillemK

Comment: Well, it is  a strange situation. It is not very often that a wired interface starts having problems. You hear more about wifi problems. Ubuntu 16.04 is a very stable version... usually. Do you remember anything that happened to it that be have caused the problems. You could consider a fresh install or even a second install if your disk has any free space.

Comment: yeah.. i will do a fresh install..

Comment: The links are dead now :-(

Answer (score 2):

If your Ethernet card is inserted into your motherboard, typing `ifconfig -a` would show eth0 even without plugging the cable in.

So, check if your Ethernet card is securely inserted into your motherboard and see if your motherboard recognize it. If not, unplug the Ethernet card and plug it in again.

Comment: That wlp6so appears only when i connect to any hotspot

Comment: Did you check if your ethernet card is securely connected to your motherboard?

Comment: I am using a laptop.. and yes it is connected properly.. i even removed and inserted it back.. my os is not recognising eth0

Comment: type `lspci` to see if it recognizes your ethernet adapter. Give us the output of that by editing your quesion.

Comment: yes i have edited the output...

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in managed connections, it may be the cause.
Move this file to another location or delete it:

```
/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices
```

Here is the bug description:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1638842

Comment: I don't have any folder or file named conf.d.. :(